# File request returns error 500

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, iis-8

I'm trying to setup a IIS server to host a WordPress site.

The site works fine, but when I try to access wp-admin, it loads the page (plain text), but all files request returns 500 error.

[image: See the image]

I've also tried: permission to root project folder and its childs, clean cache, comment .htaccess  file, increase php's memory limit, create a new folder for temporary files with all permissinos.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Status 500 can be any number of reasons. It is when the web application errors out (internal server error). I don't work with WordPress, so I can't tell anything specific to it. If there's a way to run it in a debug state, you might be able to triage it that way. This article may help though: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/ - based on it, could look if you're using plugins. But the best thing would be to look at the server logs for the timestamps where you're attempting to load it and see if it gives more information of failure.

Comment: Check php logs.